# Issue Running Jupyterhub on Https:RuntimeError: Proxy failed to start with exit code 1

Tags: python, node.js, https, proxy, jupyterhub

Hi I have installed jupyterhub on my machine and i have configured certificate and key path in jupyterhub_config.py file but i am getting the following error.

```
Error: error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read
at Error (native)
at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:85:17)
at Server (_tls_wrap.js:775:25)
at new Server (https.js:26:14)
at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:47:10)
at new ConfigurableProxy (/usr/lib/node_modules/configurable-http-proxy/lib/configproxy.js:222:32)
at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/configurable-http-proxy/bin/configurable-http-proxy:296:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
[C 2019-01-30 16:39:49.697 JupyterHub app:1867] Failed to start proxy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1865, in start
await self.proxy.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/proxy.py", line 594, in start
_check_process()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/proxy.py", line 590, in _check_process
raise e from None
RuntimeError: Proxy failed to start with exit code 1
```

Comment: Stop the notebook and run JupyterHub.

Comment: I didn't understand. I am running jupyterhub only.